# Working with functions

Tags: python, r, data-mining, data-analysis, functions

What are some good sources for learning how to deal with functions in Python and R. I have used them a lot of times and they can be a bit challenging. I like to write out a plan of what I want done when dealing with functions. Almost similar to brainstorming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might encounter many **good practices** of writing functions. I found [this one](https://codesolid.com/python-function-best-practices/) pretty good. However, if you want to start writing good code, reading about it is not sufficient. I can recommend that you **write these rules as a checklist** and evaluate your compliance with them each time after coding. It's also good to **memorise them** - spaced repetitions with Anki flashcards are the best for this goal.